# My Angular progressive web application is not searchable

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I am building an **Angular progressive web application**. I want my application to behave like a native application however I am facing some problems which should not be there if you want it to behave like a native application.

I have built it as a PWA and It is successfully adding on my home screen.The application and icon both are showing on the home screen. 
But the issue I am facing is:

- When I am searching for it, just like I am searching for other applications on my phone, then it is not coming in the list. But I have tested this scenario with the **Flipkart Lite**, I have added that to my homescreen and when I am searching for it, then it is appearing in the list of applications.

My manifest.json is:

```
{
  "name": "beautyOfSoul",
   "gcm_sender_id": "103953800507",
  "short_name": "beautyOfSoul",
  "theme_color": "#1976d2",
  "background_color": "#fafafa",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

My **app.module.ts** file is importing the service worker as:

```
environment.production ? ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js') : [], ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
```

You can find the screenshots as below:
[image]
[image]

Please let me know what can I do to achieve this.

Comment: How are you searching ? Can you post screenshot ?

Comment: @AjayS I have updated the question with screenshots

Comment: @NSharma the screenshots seem from different devices, is that correct? if so, you might want to try your PWA on the device you have Flipkart working. The reason being that the "search in Android" feature you refer to is not part of the PWA spec but rather a deeper integration that Chrome/Android offer to PWAs in Android:

• https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/integration/webapks
• https://blog.chromium.org/2017/02/integrating-progressive-web-apps-deeply.html

Comment: @HernánMagrini yes, the screenshots are from different devices. One device is supporting the search of Flipkart PWA while another doesn't. But the device which is supporting the search for Flipkart one, does not support the search for an application that I am building. It should support if it is supporting for one application.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether you have added the meta tags to your HTML. Certain mobile OS needs certain meta tags for PWA to work.

Please check this for more info on PWA meta. https://github.com/gokulkrishh/awesome-meta-and-manifest

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="application-name" content="App name">
<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="./logo.png">

<!-- Add to homescreen for Safari on iOS -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="App Name">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./logo.png">

<!-- TODO: Tile icon for Win8 (144x144 + tile color) -->
<!-- <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="ms-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png"> -->
<!-- <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#3372DF"> -->

<meta name="theme-color" content="#9fa2a3">
```